# Como usar corretamente "por que", "por quê", "porque" e "porquê"?

Tags: ortografia, uso-de-palavras, diferenças-transatlânticas

Já li varias explicações sobre a diferença entre os termos, porém muitas vezes elas deixam espaços para entendimentos diferentes e/ou não têm uma explicação sucinta sobre a forma correta de empregar os diversos *porques*. Por isso gostaria de uma explicação que preencha essas lacunas.

Também é importante reparar que existem diferenças entre o uso dos "por ques" no português europeu e no português brasileiro.

Comment: Por que se usa "por quê" com acento ao final de perguntas? Não sei porque, mas, deve haver um porquê.

Comment: Essa pergunta poderia ser expandida com explicações que levassem em conta a morfologia das palavras.

Comment: @Molx foi um ótimo exemplo

Answer (score 35, accepted):

É importante referir que esta dúvida não é tão pertinente em português europeu/de Portugal como no Brasil, porque em Portugal, as expressões não se leem da mesma maneira: "por que" e "porque" leem-se da mesma maneira, e "por quê" (que não se usa) e "porquê" leem-se da mesma maneira, mas os dois grupos são pronunciados de formas diferentes entre si.

---

## EM PORTUGUÊS DO BRASIL:

---

### Por que

Usado para perguntas.

> Por que temos que fazer novas perguntas?

### Porque

Usado para respostas.

> Porque novas perguntas fazem aparecer novas respostas.

### Por quê

Usado antes de uma pontuação interrogativa para fazer uma pergunta. Equivalente a "por qual motivo?"

> Estamos com poucas perguntas. Por quê?

### Porquê

Para se referir a uma explicação.

> Às vezes não me respondem, e não entendo o porquê.

---

## EM PORTUGUÊS EUROPEU/DE PORTUGAL:

---

### Por que

Pode ser utilizado de modo relativo

> Este é o motivo **por que** aqui estamos. = Este é o motivo **pelo qual** aqui estamos.

ou interrogativo

> **Por que** motivo trouxeste isso?

### Por quê

Não se usa para indicar causalidade ou uma explicação, apenas noutros sentidos:

> Lutamos **por quê** (=por que causas) hoje em dia?

### Porque

Pode ser utilizado enquanto advérbio interrogativo, de modo a que seja equivalente à expressão "por que motivo"

> **Porque** chegaste atrasada? = **Por que motivo** chegaste atrasada?

ou conjunção causal, de modo a que seja equivalente à expressão "visto que"

> Hoje tive que faltar **porque** houve greve de metro. = Hoje tive que faltar **visto que** houve greve de metro.

### Porquê

Pode ser utilizado enquanto substantivo

> Não entendo o **porquê** de me estares a tratar assim.

ou em interrogativas (directas ou indirectas)

> **Porquê**?
>   Chegámos tão tarde **porquê**?
>   Perguntei-te **porquê**.

[Referência](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/porque-e-por-que-como-sempre/25847)

---

## Wiki:

Como essa pergunta estava sem uma resposta completa para as variações principais do português, e nenhuma das duas respostas até então estaria completa sem a outra, e sem ignorar as boas respostas dadas pelo [jnat](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/15/jnat) e pelo [Cigano Morrison Mendez](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/29/cigano-morrison-mendez), adicionei essa resposta como wiki.

Comment: Acho que não ganhas o *bounty* com a resposta "community wiki.

Comment: +1 logo com a introdução

Comment: Méritos ao Jnat pela introdução, só fiz um ajuste, e a intenção não é o bounty, apenas uma resposta completa :)

Comment: Boa introdução ;)

Comment: Na verdade isso acontece porque Portugal foi um dos países que não ratificou e implementou o [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990). Com a língua unificada, esta resposta não fará mais sentido.

Comment: Porem por enquanto ela faz

Comment: Dúvida retirada, mesmo sendo wiki você pode receber o bounty

Comment: Estava falando no chat com isso, acho errado.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez O objectivo do acordo não é o de unificar a língua, é unificar a ortografia. De qualquer modo, esta resposta não vai deixar de fazer sentido porque se prende à gramática, e não à ortografia.

Comment: O **porquê** também é substantivado no Brasil, apenas não foi mencionado.

Comment: Se puder, acrescenta na resposta

Comment: @LucasMotta Na introdução diz-se, corretamente, que em Portugal *porque/por que* se pronuncia diferentemente de *porquê/por quê*. Isto sugere que no Brasil é tudo pronunciado da mesma maneira. Isto é verdade?

Comment: @Jacinto sim, sempre da mesma forma.

Comment: @Carlos Sim. E deve-se lembrar que, como substantivo, o termo será acentuado.

Answer (score 29):

Em português do Brasil:

## Por que

Usado para perguntas.

> Por que temos que fazer novas perguntas?

## Porque

Usado para respostas.

> Porque novas perguntas fazem aparecer novas respostas.

## Por quê

Usado antes de uma pontuação interrogativa para fazer uma pergunta. Equivalente a "por qual motivo?"

> Estamos com poucas perguntas. Por quê?

## Porquê

Para se referir a uma explicação.

> Às vezes não me respondem, e não entendo o porquê.

Comment: "Usado antes de uma pontuação para fazer uma pergunta." não seria posterior a pontuação?

Comment: `o porquê` pode ser sempre substituído por `o motivo`

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Posterior = que vem depois. Seria "anterior à pontuação" neste caso.

Comment: Bom, eu entendi que você estária se referindo a utilizado depois do . (ponto) nessa frase. Mas então está se referindo a "?". Acho que essa é uma bela base pra erro no entendimento. Pelo menos pra mim.

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Acho que nunca se usa `por quê` em português europeu. E no primeiro exemplo para `por que` também se usaria `porque`, a não ser que se pusesse `razão` antes de `temos`.

Comment: @JNat Bom, a língua foi unificada recentemente. No primeiro exemplo, "razão" é uma palavra implícita no contexto.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez vou ter de consultar alguém entendido em português mas acho que estás errado.

Comment: "Por que" tem implícito "por que razão" ou "por que motivo". Este detalhe ajuda a clarificar e a distinguir do "Porque" usado nas respostas.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez acho que deverias referenciar como português do Brasil

Comment: @JorgeB. Tem diferença? A meu ver, a gramática é a mesma para todos os países, agora que a língua é unificada.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez não viste a resposta do JNat?

Comment: Eu nunca na minha vida vi sequer "por quê" escrito em lado nenhum.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez A língua não foi unificada. Alterou-se a ortografia de muitas palavras, de maneira a que se reduza a diferença entre os dois dialectos, mas continuam a ser dois dialectos diferentes. Nós continuamos a escrever "de fa**c**to", entre outros casos. O acordo é **ortográfico**, portanto continuam a haver nuances na composição gramatical que diferem de um dialecto para o outro.

Answer (score 23):

É importante referir que esta dúvida não é tão pertinente em português europeu/de Portugal, porque as expressões não se lêem todas da mesma maneira: *por que* e *porque* lêem-se da mesma maneira, e *por quê* (que não se usa em português de Portugal) e *porquê* lêem-se da mesma maneira, mas os dois grupos são diferentes entre si.

---

**Em português europeu/de Portugal:**

## Por que

Pode ser utilizado de modo relativo, em qualquer frase onde *que* possa ser substituído por *o/a qual*, *os/as quais*

> Este é o motivo **por que** aqui estamos. = Este é o motivo **pelo qual** aqui estamos.

ou interrogativo

> **Por que** motivo trouxeste isso?

## Por quê

Não se usa, de todo. Veja-se [esta página](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-porque-e-o-por-que-e-o-portugues-europeu/30017).

## Porque

Pode ser utilizado enquanto advérbio interrogativo, de modo a que seja equivalente à expressão *por que motivo*

> **Porque** chegaste atrasada? = **Por que motivo** chegaste atrasada?

ou conjunção causal, de modo a que seja equivalente à expressão *visto que*

> Hoje tive que faltar **porque** houve greve de metro. = Hoje tive que faltar **visto que** houve greve de metro.

## Porquê

Pode ser utilizado enquanto substantivo

> Não entendo o **porquê** de me estares a tratar assim.

ou em interrogativas (directas ou indirectas)

> **Porquê**?
> Chegámos tão tarde **porquê**?
> Perguntei-te **porquê**.

---

**Em português do Brasil:**

## Por que

Pode ser utilizado de modo relativo, à semelhança do português de Portugal, em qualquer frase onde que possa ser substituído por *o/a qual*, *os/as quais*

> O caminho **por que** devo passar. = O caminho **pelo qual** devo passar.
> A razão **por que** assim procedi. = A razão **pela qual** assim procedi.

bem como enquanto locução, em perguntas, do mesmo modo que o advérbio interrogativo *porque* em português de Portugal, [uma vez que se subentende *razão*, *motivo*, etc.](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/portugal--brasil-o-uso-de-porque/4901)

> **Por que** chegou tarde? = **Por que *motivo*** chegou tarde?

## Por quê

De acordo com [esta página](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-por-que-no-fim-do-periodo-ou-isolado/10915), citando [Domingos Paschoal Cegalla](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domingos_Paschoal_Cegalla), usa-se "**por quê** no final da frase ou depois de pausa acentuada, devendo-se acentuar o **que** por ser, nesses casos, palavra tônica:"

> Os dois se hostilizam **por quê**?
> Interrogados, não quiseram dizer **por quê**.
> Estava no meio daquela multidão sem saber **por quê**.
> "Se considerava onipotente: não sabia **por quê**, mas ele acabaria por vencer, achava" (Autran Dourado, "Monte da Alegria", p.143)

Sendo, portanto, equivalente ao *porquê* do português de Portugal (exceptuando o facto de não poder ser utilizado enquanto substantivo).

## Porque

Ao contrário do português de Portugal, [só pode ser utilizado enquanto conjunção causal](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/tres-regras-para-distinguir-o-por-que-do-porque/19743), podendo também ser substituída por *visto que*

> Fiquei calada, **porque** não tinha nada para dizer. = Fiquei calada, **visto que** não tinha nada para dizer.

## Porquê

É utilizado somente enquanto substantivo

> É incompreensível o **porquê** desta discussão.

---

Mais algumas referências: [1](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/porque-e-por-que-como-sempre/25847), [2](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/que-e-que-interrogativos/31007), [3](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/duvidas-sobre-porque-e-por-que-ainda-e-sempre/23455), [4 (em relação ao português de Portugal)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/pelourinho/o-modismo-do-por-que-em-vez-de-porque/2142), [5](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-a-classificacao-do-por-que-brasil/23555), [6](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/porque-por-que-e-porque/243).

Comment: JNat então é diferente em pt_PT e pt_BR?

Comment: É. O "por que" não se usa exactamente da mesma maneira, e o "por quê" não se utiliza em português europeu.

Comment: É "Porque é que" ou "Por que é que"?

Comment: Dependerá do português que está a ser usado: em português do Brasil, *por que* subentende *razão* ou *motivo*, podendo então usar-se *Por que [motivo] é que*; em português de Portugal seria *Porque é que*, a não ser que se introduza o *motivo* subentendido no português do Brasil: *Por que motivo é que...*

Comment: A resposta ficou 5 estrelas depois da edição merecia o visto :)

Comment: Esta é para mim a melhor resposta. Mas eu preferiria uma organização por temas em vez de por país: e.g. 1) *porquê* substantivo (P + B) exemplos; 2) *porquê* (P)/ *por quê* (B), choraste porquê? (P) /choraste por quê? (B); etc. Mas pronto, eu tenho preferência pela visão global, ptPT e ptBR; outros poderão estar mais interessados numa ou noutra variante.

Comment: JNat, tu dás a conjução *porque* como equivalente a *visto que*, mas não é um bocado forçado? "A planta secou visto que não a regaste"??? "Estou com fome visto que ainda não comi nada hoje"???? Eu aqui usaria só *porque*.

Answer (score 5):

Esta resposta não difere, creio, da do JNat no que toca à substância, mas está organizada por tema, e não por país, explicando as diferenças entre o Brasil e Portugal (doravante *B* e *P*) apenas onde elas existam (basicamente, nalguns casos escreve-se *por* e *que/quê* separados no Brasil, enquanto em Portugal é tudo junto). Creio que nos países africanos a norma é igual à de Portugal.

### 1. Porque (*P* & *B*), conjunção

Pode introduzir causa ou motivo:

> Ele não veio cá porque está doente.
>
> Ele não veio cá porque não quis.

Ou uma explicação, sendo neste caso substituível por *pois, já que, visto que*, etc.:

> Ele não veio cá, porque eu estive aqui o dia todo e não o vi.

### 2. Por que (*P* & *B*), preposição + pronome relativo

‘Pelo/a qual’:

> Chegou o momento por que todos esperávamos.
>
> Desconheço os princípios por que te guias.

### 3. Por que (*P* & *B*), preposição + determinante

‘Por qual’:

> Por que razão não veio ele?
>
> Por que carga de água não queres tu convidá-lo?

### 4. (*B*) Por que / (*P*) Porque, advérbio interrogativo

‘Por que razão, motivo ou causa’

> (*B*) Por que não me contaste? / (*P*) Porque não me contaste?

É frequentemente reforçado por *é que* (ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3990/que-interrogativo)):

> (*B*) Por que é que não me contaste? / (*P*) Porque é que não me contaste?

### 5. (*B*) Por quê? /(*P*) Porquê? advérbio interrogativo

Usado em fim de frase ou isoldamente, ‘por que razão, motivo ou causa’:

> (*B*) Ele não veio por quê?/(*P*) Ele não veio porquê?
>
> Ana: Não quero ir!
> Bruno: (*B*) Por quê?!/(*P*) Porquê?!

Em Portugal (ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3475/porqu%C3%AA-e-porque-em-frases-interrogativas-infinitivas-ou-sem-verbo-no-portugu?noredirect=1&lq=1)) aparece também no meio de frases sem verbo finito (no Brasil usa-se o *por que* do ponto 4; ver [esta outra pergunta relacionada](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3339/vais-embora-amanh%C3%A3-por-qu%C3%AA-amanh%C3%A3-ou-por-que-amanh%C3%A3-em-portugu%C3%AAs-bra?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

> (*P*) Porquê esperar mais?/(*B*) Por que esperar mais?
>
> Ana: Preciso de uma agulha azul.
> Bruno: (*P*) Porquê azul?/(*B*) Por que azul?

Na verdade não existe diferença semântica entre 4 e 5. Existe é diferença na entoação da frase. O *que* (separado ou não do *por*) é átono; o *quê* (separado ou não do *por*) é tónico, pronunciado com mais ênfase, e por isso leva acento circunflexo. Não sei quão percetível é esta diferença na fala, porque em Portugal há uma diferença ainda maior que facilita tudo: *por que* ou *porque* é pronunciado como se fosse *purc* (/'puɾk/ ou /'puɾkɨ/ no alfabeto fonético internacional; podem ouvir no [Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/porque/#pt), logo o usuário aimae) enquanto *por quê* (que não se usa) ou *porquê* é pronunciado como no Brasil (/puɾ'ke/).

### 6. Porquê (*P* & *B*), substantivo masculino

Significa ‘razão, motivo, causa’:

> Não sei o porquê de tanta raiva.

### Leitura adicional

Cláudia Pinto em [Dúvida Linguística (FLiP; Priberam)](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1317). Está centrado no português de Portugal, com um nota no fim sobre as diferenças ortográficas entre Portugal e Brasil.

Answer (score 1):

Por que = Usado no início das perguntas.
Por quê? = Usado no fim das perguntas.
Porque = Usado nas respostas.
Porquê = Usado como um substantivo.