# Com a entrada em vigor do AO90, justifica-se escrever "Porque fizeste isto?" em Portugal?

Tags: ortografia, diferenças-transatlânticas, acordo-ortográfico

É sabido que, pelo menos antes do Acordo Ortográfico de 1990, o português europeu e o português brasileiro tinham convenções diferentes sobre o uso de "porque"/"por que" em interrogativas diretas e indiretas, como aliás descrito nas respostas [desta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1/como-usar-corretamente-por-que-por-qu%C3%AA-porque-ou-porqu%C3%AA).

Contudo, a força legal da norma que determinava (determina?) o uso de "porque" é, segundo João Peres e Telmo Móia em *Áreas Críticas da Língua Portuguesa* (1995), uma portaria do tempo da ditadura (p. 340-341, ortografia original):

> [...] [E]xiste um texto com força legal em Portugal, no qual se estipula a existência de uma unidade *porque* com duas realizações homónimas, pertencentes uma à categoria «conjunção» e outra à categoria «advérbio» [nota de rodapé: Trata-se do *Vocabulário Ortográfico Resumido da Língua Portuguesa* (Imprensa Nacional, Lisboa, 1970), elaborado pela Academia das Ciências de Lisboa e pela Academia Brasileira de Letras, nos termos do Decreto n.o 35 288, de 8 de Dezembro de 1945. Complementarmente, deve-se ter em conta que a Nomenclatura Gramatical Portuguesa, estabelecida pela Portaria n.o 22 664, de 27 de Abril de 1967, do Ministro da Educação Nacional, mantém a classe de palavras «advérbio interrogativo de causa».]

Ora os autores consideram arbitrário grafar *porque* nos casos daquilo a que tradicionalmente se chama subordinadas causais (p.342), mas acima de tudo não consideram «minimamente fundamentada» a norma que determina em Portugal o uso de *porque* como constituinte interrogativo (p. 343):

> Este tipo de construção é sem dúvida o mais problemático no que respeita à definição de uma norma minimamente fundamentada. Numa tentativa de clarificação, saliente-se, em primeiro lugar, que a expressão *que* é também neste caso um elemento pronominal, independentemente de se considerar ou não que ele precede uma posição nominal vazia. Trata-se, na verdade, exactamente do mesmo tipo de *que* que encontramos associado a uma posição argumental nas frases de (1228) [a. Por que luta a maria (com o sentido de: *por que coisas luta a Maria?*); b. Por que é que a Maria trocou a minha prenda? (com o sentido de: *por que coisas trocou a Maria a minha prenda?*] ou a uma posição não argumental, com valor final, na frase seguinte:
>     (1231) **Para que** fizeste isso?
>   Temos, pois, de concluir que não há -- muito pelo contrário! -- qualquer razão imperativa de carácter semântico ou sintáctico para que em construções com as características semântico-sintáticas de (1230) se aplique a justaposição -- isto é, se use *porque* em vez de *por que*. [...] [S]ó uma convenção pode impor tal procedimento. Ora, como já vimos, tal convenção foi estabelecida para Portugal por diploma legal, ao contrário do que acontece no Brasil, onde a norma oficial determina a separação. Cremos que a a clareza estrutural da língua talvez tivesse algo a ganhar se, neste particular, Portugal seguisse a prática brasileira [...].

Foi a portaria de 1967 revogada? Existe uma outra em vigor no mesmo sentido? Em interrogativas, pode hoje em dia usar-se (ou tem mesmo de se usar) *por que* em Portugal?

Comment: Excelente pergunta à qual também quero uma resposta cabal :) No ponto 1c), João Henriques [no ciberduvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/porque-por-que-e-porque/243), discorda do caro amigo.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo o [ciberduvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/porque-por-que-e-porque/243) "por que" tem significado similar a "por qual", e "porque" tem significado similar a "por qual motivo/razão".

Portanto a forma correta será escrever:

> Por que motivo fizeste isto?

ou

> Porque fizeste isto?

Se omitirmos o "motivo", escrevendo "porque fizeste isto", ficamos com uma frase com significado similar a "por qual fizeste isto" o que não faz sentido.

Comment: Quando escreveste «[s]e omitirmos o "motivo", escrevendo "porque fizeste isto"», querias ter escrito «[s]e omitirmos o "motivo", escrevendo "**por que** fizeste isto"»?

Answer (score -1):

De acordo com este [site](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/porque-por-que-e-porque/243) a utilização mais correta da pergunta ''Porque fizeste isso?'' seria ''Por que fizeste isso?'', pois explica no site que 'por que' utiliza-se quando se pergunta por uma razão como: ''**Por que '*razão*' fizeste isso**?'

Portanto eu opto por 'Por que'. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Receio que tenhas interpretado mal o link que deste, o qual diz **exatamente o contrário**: "Escreve-se _porque_ ... c) Quando é advérbio interrogativo: «Porque não vens comigo?» «Porque faz ele isto?»". Em todo o caso eu sei qual são as regras (pelo menos pré-acordo) em relação ao uso de _porque_ e _por que_, distintas em Portugal e no Brasil. O que estou a perguntar é se a alteração do quadro legislativo com a entrada em vigor do acordo altera alguma coisa.