# «Porquê» e «porque» em frases interrogativas infinitivas ou sem verbo no português europeu

Tags: gramática, português-europeu, sintaxe

No português brasileiro, para além de este *porquê* ser grafado *por quê*, e este *porque*, *por que*, existe outras diferenças neste tipo de frases, as quais são tratadas [nesta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3339/vais-embora-amanh%C3%A3-por-qu%C3%AA-amanh%C3%A3-ou-por-que-amanh%C3%A3-em-portugu%C3%AAs-bra). No português europeu, neste tipo de frase, usa-se *porquê* em frases afirmativas, mas *porque* em frases negativas. Por exemplo:

> João: — Vamos lá para fora?
>
> Ana, que não vê razão para ir lá para fora: — Porquê?
>
> Ana, que acha boa ideia ir lá para fora: — Porque não?

De igual modo, em interrogações infinitivas:

> Porquê jantar fora hoje?
>
> Porque não jantar fora hoje?

Porquê esta diferença entre frases negativas e afirmativas? Note-se que esta diferença nem vem sancionada no dicionário da Academia ou no Houaiss (edição portuguesa), que simplesmente indicam *porquê* para frases interrotivas infinitivas sem excluir frases negativas (mas também sem incluir exemplos delas). Mas eu tenho praticamente a certeza que que em Portugal toda a gente fala como nos meus exemplos.

Os *porquês, porquês*, etc. já deram pano para mangas. Para além da pergunta mencionada acima, vejam [esta pergunta sobre *porque, por que, porquê* e *por quê*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1/como-usar-corretamente-por-que-por-qu%C3%AA-porque-ou-porqu%C3%AA) e mais [esta sobre *porque* em frases interrogativas no português europeu](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1612/com-a-entrada-em-vigor-do-ao90-justifica-se-escrever-porque-fizeste-isto-em).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece ser mais uma questão prosódica. Repara:

> a) Por quê não levar este?
>   b) Por que não levar este?

<sub>(Em Portugal, escreve-se geralmente junto: *Porquê não…?*, *Porque não…?*)</sub>

A primeira frase lês com uma pausa após *quê*, a segunda sem essa pausa. O significado também difere um pouco. Com *quê*, a interpretação favorecida é pedir-se uma justificação para não levar qualquer coisa, enquanto com *que* tenderá a ser lido mais como uma sugestão.

Curiosamente, como aponta [Carlos Rocha no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pronomes-interrogativos-o-que-e-o-que/28814), mas sem apontar explicação, o comportamento de *que* / *o que* é distinto:

> (1) Queres fazer **o quê**?
>   (2) **Que/O que/*O quê** queres fazer?

Infelizmente, também não consegui encontrar nada de muito substancial sobre o assunto. Por exemplo, na gramática de Maria Mateus (6.ª ed., 2003), parece apenas uma nota de rodapé no capítulo sobre elipse da autoria de Gabriela Mateus (p. 905):

> Em **Truncamento** [*sluicing*] o constituinte elíptico é introduzido por um sintagma interrogativo:
>
> (66) (...) (e) A: Trouxe um presente para a Maria.
>   B: Pode saber-se o quê *[<sub>SFLEX</sub> -]*
>   [<sub>SFLEX</sub> -] = trouxeste para a Maria
>
> [nota de rodapé: Repare-se que a forma tónica *o quê* só surge quando o constituinte frásico está omitido, como no exemplo dado, ou quando este consituinte interrogado se encontra na posição básica, sem ter sido movido, como em (i):
>         (i) Trouxeste o quê para a Maria.]

A *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian tem uma nota ainda mais breve também a propósito do *sluicing* (aqui denominado de *elipse parcial da oração interrogativa*, p. 2374) e escrito pela mesma autora, Gabriela Mateus:

> <sup>43</sup> Repare-se que não há uma coincidência formal  entre a forma tónica do constituinte interrogativo *o quê* que ocorre na oração hospedeira do exemplo [Pode saber-se o̲ ̲q̲u̲ê̲ <del>trouxeste para a Maria?</del>] e a forma átona que ocorre na oração correspondente sem elipse [...]. Esta alternância deve-se a fatores fonológicos.

Portanto, “fatores fonológicos”; mas não encontro nada mais detalhado.

Vendo estas frases, parece também fazer alguma diferença o infinitivo ter desinências:

> 1. A questão que resta é: por quê/*que irmos nós e não eles?
> 2. A questão que resta é: por quê/?que escolher este e não aquele?
> 3. Não temos/há com quê/que lavarmos as mãos.
> 4. Não temos/há com quê/que lavar as mãos.

As 3. e 4., não sei bem que dizer delas, à parte de que a opção que prefiro é *Não temos/há com que lavar as mãos*.

Comment: No fundo isto é o mesmo tipo de explicação avançado na resposta à pergunta paralela sobre o português brasileiro (só que aí eu não tenho tanta sensibilidade).

Comment: Então rebelaste-te de vez contra o *porque* e *porquê* interrogativos? Talvez devesses escrever uma resposta à tua pergunta.

Comment: Eu não consigo ler em voz alta essa frase " Por quê não levar este?", parece não fazer sentido nenhum.

Comment: @JorgeB. E que tal: _Eu percebo todas as outras restrições. Mas porquê não poder levar este?_

Comment: @Jacinto Acho que aqui causaria mais confusão. Não creio que para esta pergunta faça diferença estarmos a tratar _por que_ / _por quê_ ou _com que_ / _com quê_ ou _para que_ / _para quê_. Em todo o caso, deixei uma nota.

Comment: @Artefacto soa muito estranho "...Mas porquê não poder..." faz parecer um estrangeiro que não sabe ainda falar muito bem o português.

Comment: @JorgeB. Claramente não é tão bom como "mas porque é que não se pode...", mas a mim não me parece completamente impossível.