# É possível usar o termo "porque" em frases interrogativas?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática

As regras do uso dos porquês são muito difundidas pela internet. Geralmente, diz-se que o *por que*, separado, deve ser usado para frases interrogativas. Já o *porque*, junto, deve ser utilizado nas demais frases.

Entretanto, eu desconfio dessas regras simplistas, que servem apenas para induzir o estudante a memorizar informações sem se preocupar em aprender ou assimilar o conhecimento.

Por isso, com a leitura que eu faço da gramática, entendo que o *porque*, junto, pode ser escrito em frases interrogativas sem prejuízo da validade quando se quer introduzir a ideia de explicação ou causalidade.

Por exemplo, com o intuito de perguntar se a causa da prisão foi o roubo dos tomates, estaria gramaticalmente correta a frase interrogativa "ele foi preso porque roubou tomates?".

Enfim, há alguma incorreção na possibilidade de usar o *porque* em frases interrogativas? Há referências externas sobre esse assunto?

Comment: Incluí a tag português-brasileiro porque no europeu esta diferenciação [não é tão importante](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3475/2764).

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: [Como usar corretamente “por que”, “por quê”, “porque” e “porquê”?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1/2764).

Comment: Geralmente, a regra simplista enfatiza que o emprego do "por que", separado sem acento, ocorre em frases interrogativas quando ele entra como sinônimo de "por qual razão" ou "por qual motivo". Não diz que outras formas não ocorrem em outras circunstâncias. Assim, me parece que a sua construção não viola a regra simplista usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, tu podes utilizar o *porque* em perguntas interrogativas.

### Uso do *Porque*

A forma *porque* tem bastantes classificações. São elas:

- Conjunção Subordinativa Causais
- Conjunção Subordinativa Finais
- Conjunção Coordenativa Explicativa

**Conjunção Subordinativa Causal**

São as conjunções que exprimem a causa, a razão de um efeito.

> Ex.: *Porque* eu te amo intensamente, muitas pessoas sentem ciúmes de nós?

**Conjunções Subordinativa Finais**

São aquelas que exprimem finalidade, objetivo, intuito, propósito, fim.

> Ex.: Ore *porque* não caia em tentação.

Nessa classe podemos substituir o termo *porque* pelo *para que*.

**Conjunção Coordenativa Explicativa**

Esta classe serve para exprimir ideia de explicação, justificativa; normalmente a conjunção vem após verbos no imperativo.

> Ex.: Não demore, *porque* sairemos em breve.

### Uso do *Por que*

A forma *por que* — tal qual o *porque* — tem mais de uma classificação possível. São elas:

- Locução Adverbial Interrogativa;
- Preposição + Conjunção integrante;
- Pronome Preposicionado

**Locução adverbial interrogativa**

Essa classe serve, como o próprio nome já diz, para estabelecer uma pergunta. Ela pode aparecer tanto em perguntas diretas, quanto em indiretas.

> Ex.: *Por que* tu fizeste isso?

> Ex.: Não sei *por que* insisto tanto em te querer.

Também podemos trocar o termo supra por:

- *por qual razão*
- *por qual motivo*
- *(o) motivo pelo qual* (no meio de orações)

**Preposição + Conjunção integrante**

Nessa classe, temos uma coincidência, visto que a conjunção integrante serve para introduzir orações substantivas na oração principal.

> Ex.: Eu sempre ansiei *por que* você me explicasse o motivo.

Observe que na frase acima, o verbo *ansiar* — nesse contexto — é *transitivo indireto*, pois pede a preposição na pergunta.

*Quem anseia, anseia **por** algo*

**Pronome Preposicionado**

De acordo com Rocha Lima, o *por que* quando podendo trocar por: *pelo qual*, *pela qual*, *pelos quais* ou pelas quais. É classificado como um pronome interrogativo preposicionado.

> Ex.: São estes os motivos *por que (pelos quais)* não compareceu.

### Como diferenciar o *porque* do *por que*

Normalmente, as pessoas têm o mau costume de decorar regras da língua portuguesa. Por isso bastantes pessoas confundem-se com algumas regras.

O *porque*, tal qual *por que* também pode ser usado numa pergunta. Normalmente ele é usado em perguntas cuja resposta é: sim, não, talvez, depende etc.

> Ex.: *Porque* ele não veio à festa foi cancelada?
>
> Ex.: *Porque* ele não veio, a festa foi cancelada?

A primeira dica é observar se a entonação da pergunta recai no termo *por que*. Caso recaia, utiliza-se separado; caso contrário, junto.

Exemplo:

> “— **Por que** choras, senhor conde? Desafogue essa agonia.
>   Dê-me tua tristeza e dar-te-ei a minha alegria.”

Na segunda dica, tomaremos como exemplo a frase *"Será porque ele viajou mais de 20 horas na classe econômica que está cansado?"*

Para descobrirmos qual termo utilizar, devemos ignorar o verbo *ser* + *que*, que formam uma expressão expletiva. Feito isso, passaremos a frase para a ordem direta.

> Ele está cansado **porque** (= pois) viajou mais de 20 horas na classe econômica?

***Referências***

<sup>PESTANA, Fernando. **A Gramática para Concursos: TEORIA PROFUNDAMENTE COMPLETA E MAIS DE 1.300 QUESTÕES ATUAIS E COMENTADAS.** [S. l.]: Editora Método Ltda., 2013.</sup>
<sup>BECHARA, Evanildo. Os principais tipos de adjuntos adverbiais. In: BECHARA, Evanildo. **Moderna Gramática Portuguesa.** [S. l.]: Nova Fronteira, 2012.</sup>

Comment: Eu — quase sempre — excedo-me nas palavras. Caso a resposta fuja um pouco da pergunta ou esteja longa demais, peço que me ajudem a resumi-la.