# Diferença entre porque e "por que" como forma interrogativa

Tags: gramática, português-europeu, semântica

A propósito ainda das diferenças subtis entre **porque** e **por que**, apenas cingidas à forma interrogativa, [esta outra resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1/como-usar-corretamente-por-que-por-qu%C3%AA-porque-ou-porqu%C3%AA) não é totalmente clara sobre esta matéria. O filólogo José Neves Henriques da Universidade de Lisboa, [faz esta distinção](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/porque-por-que-e-porque/243):

1- Escreve-se **porque**:

> Quando é *advérbio interrogativo*: 
> Exemplo: «**Porque** não vens comigo?»
>   «**Porque** faz ele isto?»

2 – Escreve-se **por que**:

> Quando **por** é *preposição* e o **que** é *pronome interrogativo adjunto*:
>   (chama-se adjunto por vir junto dum substantivo, ligado ele pelo
>   sentido).
> Exemplos: «**Por que** (= por qual) razão/motivo/causa/pretexto,
>   etc., não vieste ontem?» «**Por que** (= por quais) livros aprendeste?»

Significa então que a regra é saber se a seguir à palavra interrogativa (que ou porque) vem um substantivo ou um verbo?

Ou seja "por que motivo chove?" e "porque é que chove?". É esta a diferença?

Comment: A pergunta se refere ao pt-PT, correto? Porque as citações não se aplicam ao pt-BR.

Comment: @stafusa correto!

Comment: Por qué e porqué faltam.

Comment: Basicamente. Não é uma regra muito consistente ([ver esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1612/com-a-entrada-em-vigor-do-ao90-justifica-se-escrever-porque-fizeste-isto-em)). Nota que não tem de ser um substantivo a seguir-se, pode outro sintagma nominal: _por que abstrusa razão…_, possivelmente vazio: _por que [coisa] esperas_

Comment: Mas de acordo com a fonte seria `porque coisa esperas?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deve-se dizer: "Por que motivo chove?" "Porque chove?"

Se parece confuso, a resposta pode ajudar:

1. "Por [que motivo] chove? Chove por [causa das alterações climáticas]."
2. "Porque chove cá dentro? Chove porque nós temos um buraco no telhado."

Repare-se que na segunda resposta, a palavra "porque" é uma conjunção que aglutina duas orações totalmente autónomas: "Chove"/"nós temos um buraco no telhado". Enquanto na primeira resposta a palavra "por" é uma preposição - e temos apenas uma oração, e não duas: "Chove por (uma razão qualquer...)"

Assim, quando se diz "Por que .... ?", muitas vezes o "que" é seguido de um nome comum do tipo "razão", "motivo", ou outro (que não tem que ser sinónimo de motivo...).

Exs: "Por que caminho vais?" "Por que razão estás aqui?" "Por que candidato votaste?"

Quando se diz "Porque ....?", o "Porque" (advérbio) é seguido por uma frase autónoma.

Ex: "Porque tu mataste essa formiga?" (tu vem usualmente omisso ou invertido com mataste)

É de notar que esta regra aplica-se ao português de Portugal. No Brasil existem algumas diferenças.

Comment: No Brasil, a regra que se usa é: "Por que" para pergunta, "Porque" para resposta, "... por quê?" no final da frase para pergunta, "porquê" sinônimo de motivo/razão. Todavia um falante comum entenderá perfeitamente se apenas os dois primeiros forem utilizados, embora o uso de "porquê", com acento, seja recomendado para diferenciar conjunção de substantivo.