# Qual é a diferença entre "por que" e "para que"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, significado-em-contexto

Qual é a diferença entre ***por que*** e ***para que***?

Eles são alternativos, ou seja posso usar um no lugar de outro. Exemplo:

> Para que perder tempo planejando o futuro?

Posso falar assim?

> Por que perder tempo planejando o futuro?

Que tal: *Por que perco tempo planejando o futuro?*

Comment: São diferentes. Por exemplo, se me perguntaram “por que roes a unha?”, respondo “porque virou hábito”; se me perguntaram “para que roes a unha?”, respondo “para nada, só faço pela força do hábito”. Em vários situações, porém, o objetivo e a razão são iguais.

Comment: Obrigado. Poderia dar mais exemploes. Não tou entendendo bem.

Comment: Majid, “para (que)” indica intenção, finalidade ou objetivo, e “porque(ê)” e “por que(ê)” indicam motivo ou razão. Basicamente.

Comment: Secundo o que Schilive comenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Para que*** é usado para perguntar o objetivo, a finalidade. Exemplos:

> Para que é essa farinha? (= Qual é a finalidade da farinha?)
> É para fazer pão.
>
> Para que queres essa bota velha? (= Qual é a finalidade da bota?)
> Vou enchê-la de terra e plantar lá uma flor.

***Por que*** é usado para perguntar a causa, a razão:

> Por que**¹** é que a planta morreu? (= Qual é a causa da morte da planta?)
> Porque foi atacada por uma parasita.
>
> Por que é que o menino está chorando? (= Qual é a causa de o menino estar chorando?)
> Porque perdeu o boneco favorito dele.

Neste último exemplo, se perguntasses *para que é que o menino está chorando*? estarias a insinuar que o menino estava a chorar de propósito, forçadamente, com o algum objetivo em mente, para conseguir alguma coisa de alguém.

Agora há situações em que não faz grande diferença perguntar o objetivo ou a razaão. Por exemplo, imagina que vamos fazer um viajem de carro, e eu proponho começarmos logo às seis da manhã:

> Para que queres sair tão cedo? (= Qual é o teu objetivo em sair tão cedo?)
> É para chegarmos lá antes da hora do almoço.
>
> Por que queres sair tão cedo? (= Qual é a razão de quereres sair tão cedo?)
> Porque quero chegar lá antes da hora o almoço.

Repara que no primeiro caso se pergunta o objetivo; no segundo, a razão; mas a informação que passa é a mesma. Porque o objetivo fornece a razão: se eu tenho o objetivo de chegar lá antes do almoço, querer atingir esse objetivo é uma boa razão para sair cedo. De tal maneira que é frequente uma pessoa perguntar a razão (*por que*) e a outra responder com o objetivo (*para que*):

> **Por que** queres sair tão cedo?
> É **para** chegarmos lá antes da hora do almoço.

Nos teu exemplos, podes fazer qualquer das duas perguntas, e o efeito prático é o mesmo, apesar de num caso perguntares o objetivo, no outro, a razão:

> Por que**²** perder tempo planejando o futuro? (= Qual a razão de fazer isso?)
>
> Para que**³** perder tempo planejando o futuro? (= Qual o objetivo de fazer isso?)

O efeito prático é o mesmo porque se tiveres um objetivo, quereres atingir esse objetivo é uma boa razão. Além do mais, a pergunta é retórica, isto é, se a pessoa fala em “perder tempo”, é porque não acredita que exista uma razão ou objetivo válidos.

Também podes perguntar *por que perco tempo planejando o futuro?* A diferença é que neste estás falando de ti mesmo. Nos outros exemplos, *por/para que perder*... podes estar a falar de ti mesmo ou de outras pessoas quaisquer.

---

Notas:
    **¹** Este *por que* segue a norma brasileira. Em Portugal escreve-se tudo junto, *porque*. É o mesmo        em todos os outros exemplos desta resposta exceto o último (ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1/como-usar-corretamente-por-que-por-qu%C3%AA-porque-e-porqu%C3%AA)).
    **²** Este *por que* é norma brasileira. Em Portugal escreve-se *porquê* (ver [ponto 5 desta resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1/como-usar-corretamente-por-que-por-qu%C3%AA-porque-e-porqu%C3%AA/5684#5684)).
    **³** Novamente, este *para que* é norma brasileira. Em Portugal é *para quê* (pela mesma razão que       o *porquê* do ponto anterior).

Answer (score 0):

Baseado no exemplos da sua pergunta, **por que/por quê/porquê** são utilizados para fazer perguntas (porquê não é usado com essa finalidade no portugues brasileiro).

Já **para que** é normalmente usando para explicar motivo, razão, intenção, objetivo, como nesses exemplos:

Para que seja possível finalizar a compra.....
Para que aconteça dessa forma....
Para que não seja esquecido...
Para que haja disponibilidade...
Vou fazer isso para que me ajude...

No caso do seu exemplo

> Para que perder tempo planejando o fututo?

Isso não é comum, principalmente no português escrito, já no português falado é mais comum, inclusive reduzido para "Pra que perder tempo?", mas poderia ser uma ajuda quando se tem dúvida na forma de usar o "porque" nesse caso. Para uma pergunta, se usado no início da frase deveria ser usado "Por que", separado e sem acento.

Comment: Ricardo, não entendi: falaste que os porquês, excetuando-se “porque”, são usados para perguntar e “para que” é usado para responder, mas usaste “para que” numa pergunta. Qual é a diferença entre “por que” e “para que”?

Comment: use para citar o exemplo que está na própria pergunta *"Para que perder tempo planejando o fututo?"*, Para perguntas geralmente se usa "porque/por que", mas o "para que" tem sentido de motivo, razão. Um exemplo que caberia bem seria "Para que serve isso"? ou seja no sentido de "Qual o motivo disso?"

Comment: Ricardo, acho que “para que” tem outro significado, como eu disse nos comentários da pergunta e como diz o Priberam: “Indica o fim, o objectivo ou a consequência de determinada acção”. Acho que o motivo de “para que” e “por que” serem equivalentes em algumas frases é porque a razão e o objetivo são iguais. Digo “razão” porque. como diz o Priberam, “conjunção
1. Por motivo de; em razão de (ex.: Estavam cansados, porque caminharam muito).

advérbio interrogativo
2. [Portugal]  Usa-se para questionar a causa de algo (ex.: Porque fizeste isso?).”.

Comment: Ricardo, mas o que eu realmente quisera dizer é que eu não consegui ver uma resposta à pergunta.

Comment: Ricardo, obrigado pela resposta. Mas "por que"  não está também utilizado para falar os motivos, razaões de alguma coiza?

Comment: @Majid, sim, estás certo. O Proberam define “por que” como “conjunção 1. Por motivo de; em razão de (ex.: Estavam cansados, porque caminharam muito). advérbio interrogativo 2. [Portugal] Usa-se para questionar a causa de algo (ex.: Porque fizeste isso?).”. O Priberam está se referindo à grafia portuguesa, mas os quartos porquês seguem a mesma ideia.