# Por que não eliminamos os quatro porquês do português?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, ortografia

O português brasileiro tem quatro palavras com a mesma pronúncia de "porquê":

- *por que*
- *por quê*
- *porque*
- *porquê*

Talvez por costume percebamos os 4 porquês, mas por que não os eliminamos e usamos apenas uma grafia?

Comment: Primeiro, o título não faz sentido, e segundo, preserbamos não existe.

Comment: O motivo de usarmos *por que*, separado, é que usamos como separado. Assim como *de que* e *a que*. A expressão *por que matou?* = *o que é aqulo pelo qual matou?*. Agora, em teoria, poderíamos usar *por que* também para responder. Então, não entendo o motivo de se ter *porque* junto.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Como usar corretamente "por que", "por quê", "porque" e "porquê"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1/como-usar-corretamente-por-que-por-qu%c3%aa-porque-e-porqu%c3%aa)

Comment: A razão é porque cada um tem um sentido diferente.

Answer (score 2):

Nada impede uma pessoa de usar uma grafia própria em seus textos — de fato é o que muitos já fazem, quer usufruindo da liberdade poética, quer por desconhecimento de ou indiferença à norma culta/clássica. Então a questão é como levar *outras pessoas* a adotarem uma dada grafia.

No caso de português brasileiro, mudanças oficiais na língua (as quais são implementadas em livros escolares e assim acabam por se estabelecer) costumam ser ditadas por instituições como a Academia Brasileira de Letras (ABL). Tais instituições costumam prezar pela tradição e resistem com especial vigor a mudanças que considerem violar origens etimológicas ou reduzir a consistência ou o caráter do idioma. E a verdade é que, tradicionalistas como são, mesmo as mudanças que a ABL se decide por implementar frequentemente encontram resistência dentro da sociedade.

Então, em parte por mera inércia ("costume"), mas em parte também por argumentos linguísticos ou estéticos, a razão de não adotarmos uma grafia única é a dificuldade de convencer todo mundo a fazê-lo.